# Need explanation of jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain the structure of this line of a script for me? Another user on here has written it as part of a function that I know want to edit and change to use elsewhere on my site.

```
    $('#main_content .img-wrapper').empty().append($(this).find('img').clone());
```

This one takes an image from one div and copies it to another with the class="img-wrapper"

I want to do exactly the same but with text. I tried this

```
$('#main_content .text-wrapper').empty().append($(this).find('.info').clone());
```

where ('.info') is the class name of the div I want to copy. Its not working.

I don't fully understand the syntax as this is my first day using javascript. Please can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

This is the HTML - There are four different images and when the user clicks on each of the image I want it to load the same image and associated text in the main content div

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="back">
      <img src="images1.png" />
      <div class="info" style="display: none;">This is a test for image one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="front"  style="background-color:#cc99cc;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="back">
      <img src="images2.png" />
      <div class="info" style="display: none;">This is a test for image one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="front"  style="background-color:#9966cc;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="back">
      <img src="images3.png" />
      <div class="info" style="display: none;">This is a test for image one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="front"  style="background-color:#6666cc;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="back">
      <img src="images4.png" />
      <div class="info" style="display: none;">This is a test for image one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="front"  style="background-color:#3366cc;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the main content div

```
<div id="main_content">
  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="img-wrapper">
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rob W "jQuery is..." oh, bah

Comment: Why are you cloning elements if it's just text? You can just retrieve the text as a string an set it on some other element...

Comment: Do you have more than one .info div ? What's the HTML markup look like?

Comment: Start at http://api.jquery.com and read the parts you need to understand. I'm afraid that if this is your first day using JavaScript, you've got a long way to go.

Comment: [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty) [append](http://api.jquery.com/append) [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone)

Comment: http://jqfundamentals.com/ great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#main_content .text-wrapper').empty().append($(this).find('.info').html());
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. this is the site www.samueljamesdesign.com

I do freelance print design and thought it was about time I had a website for my portfolio

Is this a bad way of achieving what Im trying to achieve? The site currently only works in chrome and safari, I will be fixing the glitches once my knowledges expands... Very new to web design

many thanks

Sam

Answer (score 2):

The javascript in question is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$('#main_content .img-wrapper')
```

returns the element(s) with class 'img-wrapper' inside the element with id 'main_content'

```
.empty()
```

empties this element (removes all it's HTML contents)

```
.append(
```

inserts the argument (the bit that comes next) into this element

```
     $(this).find('img')
```

finds all 'img' tags within the element referred to by `this` (i.e. if this was triggered from a `.click()` handler then the element that was clicked)

```
     .clone()
```

clones these elements so that there are two versions - one in their original location and one being inserted into the `#main_content img-wrapper` element.

```
);
```

Do you definitely have a `#main_content .text-wrapper` element?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Its very clear and helped me understand far better :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html structure, my guess would be the context in which you're trying to find `.info` is incorrect.

I'm assuming this block of code is within an event handler like a click or mouseover or something. In that case the `$(this)` is referring to the element that triggered that event. So the following snippet:

```
$(this).find('.info')
```

is looking for elements with a classname of `info` **within** the element referred to by `$(this)`.

Make sure the context is correct - change `$(this)` to the element that you need to search within.

Comment: Hi Swatkins,

This is correct the class name is within the element I am referring to. Emre answer below worked but being new I'm unsure as to why this is the case

Comment: the `clone()` method creates a copy of an element, so when you need to place an image somewhere else, that's what you'd use. the `html()` method will grab the html code **within** an element, so if you're looking to move text somewhere else, that's what you'd use.